# Proof on Intersection of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I could not understand this property:
NOTE: P(A) is the Power Set.
$$P(A\cap B) = P(A)\cap P(B)$$
$$PROOF (\text{ Just the first part})$$
Consider an element say $a\in P(A\cap B)$. Then,
$$a\in P(A\cap B)$$
$$\Longrightarrow a\subseteq A\cap B$$
$$a\subseteq A \text{ and }a\subseteq B$$
$$a\in P(A) \text{ and }a\in P(B)$$
$$a\in P(A)\cap P(B)$$
$$\Longrightarrow P(A\cap B)\subseteq P(A)\cap P(B)$$
Could somebody explain the last step: how we get $P(A\cap B)\subseteq P(A)\cap P(B)$? How does the sequence of steps mean that $P(A\cap B)\subseteq P(A)\cap P(B)$? How do we get $P(A\cap B)$ as a subset?

Comment: What exactly is "$P$"?

Comment: Ok got it, thanks for the clarification.  Had you put $2^A$ for $P(A)$ I think more people would understand.

Comment: @GregoryGrant: Not necessarily more people, just another set of people.

Comment: No, $|2^A|$ is the number, $2^A$ is the set itself.

Comment: @celtschk I would think everybody would understand $2^A$ while when I saw $P(A)$ I immediately started thinking "Probability function".

Comment: @GregoryGrant: Then you would think wrong.

Comment: @celtschk Are you saying you are an example of a person who doesn't know what $2^A$ means?  The nice thing about $2^A$ is that it has a universal definition anybody could easily look up.  While $P(A)$ is context specific and vague.  So it cannot be looked up.  QED, I rest my case.

Comment: @GregoryGrant: I know what $2^A$ means, basically because I learned it here on math.SE. Before that, I didn't (but I definitely knew what a power set is, and knew the notation $P(A)$ for it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You started the proof with the assumption that
$$a\in P(A\cap B)$$
and ended with the conclusion that
$$a\in P(A)\cap P(B)$$
You have thus shown that there is an implication
$$a\in P(A\cap B)\to a\in P(A)\cap P(B)$$
which just means, since $a$ is arbitrary, that any member of the set $P(A\cap B)$ must also be a member of the set $P(A)\cap P(B)$: this is precisely the definition of a subset. Therefore we can conclude:
$$P(A\cap B)\subseteq P(A)\cap P(B)$$

Comment: Asking exactly the same doubt Sir: wouldn't it be better to start the proof with $\forall s\in S. s\in T \Rightarrow S\subseteq T$ instead of taking s as an arbitrary element of S?

Comment: @BetterWorld If we started by the assumption "everything in $S$ has some property", then if we reached a contradiction, we would have to conclude that "not everything in $S$ has that property", instead of "everything in $S$ doesn't have that property". Therefore, considering only an arbitrary member of $S$ is more advantageous: if something is true of that arbitrary member, then it must also be true of all members of $S$; and if something is false of that arbitrary, then it must also be false of all members of $S$.

Answer (score 1):

In general to show a set $S$ is contained in another set $T$ you take any element $s\in S$ and show $s\in T$.  Therefore any element in $S$ is in $T$.  It must be then that $S\subseteq T$.  That's the logic of that step in the proof.

Comment: Sir, but how do we show this? How does a single element $s\in S$and $s\in T$ prove that $S\subseteq T$?

Comment: Because $s$ is chosen to be an *arbitrary* element of $S$.  So we essentially showed $s\in S$ $\Rightarrow$ $s\in T$.  It follows that $S\subseteq T$.  Suppose by contradiction that $S\not\subseteq T$.  Then $\exists$ $s\in S$ such that $s\not\in T$. But we showed $s\in S$ $\Rightarrow$ $s\in T$ so this is a contradiction.  So $S\subseteq T$.

Comment: Sir, I didn't understand this symbol:$\exists$  and consequently, couldn't understand what you were saying

Comment: Sorry about that, $\exists$ means "there exists"

Comment: OK, Sir. But wouldn't it be better to prove $\forall s\in S. s\in T \Rightarrow S\subseteq T$ instead of taking s as an arbitrary element of S?

Comment: In other words, Sir, how do we show that if the property for a particular element $s\in S\Rightarrow s\in T\Rightarrow S\subseteq T$ is true, then it is true for all $s\in S$?

Comment: @BetterWorld  Before I can answer your question, in your statement $\forall$ $s\in S$.$s\in T$ $\Rightarrow$ $S\subseteq T$, what exactly does the period between $S$ and $s$ mean?

Comment: Soory Sir, I modified it but for some reason it did not show in the comment above. I meant this, Sir:
Let us take 2 sets S and T. Sir, we show that for a particular element $s\in S$, the property $s\in S\Rightarrow s\in T$ is true. Sir, how can we extend this property to all elements in S?

Comment: Because nowhere in the proof did you use any property of $s$ that didn't apply to *all* $s$.  If you argue that an *arbitrary* element of $S$ is in $T$ like that, which is what you have done in the proof, then it evidently follows for all elements.

Comment: This is very standard math, if you keep studying you will see it done all the time, so get used to it.  You let $s\in S$ and you show, without using any property of $s$ that does not apply to all $s$, that $s\in T$.  From there it must be that $S\subseteq T$.

Comment: Alright Sir, thanks a lot!

Comment: Just make sure that it makes sense to you.  If it doesn't now, with a bit of experience it will.

Answer (score 1):

If you show that every member of $X$ is a member of $Y$, you conclude that $X\subset Y$.  That's what "$\subset$" means.

**Postscript inspired by a comment below:**

It is not true that if just one element of $S$ is an element of $T$ then $S\subset T$.  But consider this argument.  "Let $s$ be a member of $S$.  Then we can show by the following argument that $s$ is purple."  Here you're proving that $s$ is purple by using **no information about $s$ except that $s\in S$.**  If you can do that, then it follows that **every** member of $s$ is purple.

Comment: Sir, let us take 2 sets S and T. Sir, we show that for a particular element $s\in S$, the property $s\in S\Rightarrow s\in T$ is true.  Sir, how can we extend this property to all elements in ${S}$?

Comment: @BetterWorld Because all the elements $s_i$ of $S$ possess the same property, namely that they are in $S$: $s_i\in S$. This is what Michael means by "no information about $s$ except that $s\in S$". We show that anything that is in $S$ has some property, then ask "but what is in $S$?" - all the members of $S$.